# How to catch an error coming from a Future in flutter widget test?

Tags: flutter, error-handling, dart, flutter-test

I'm facing an issue while doing widget testing on a widget that throws an exception during a `Future`.

**Code to reproduce the problem**

Here's a simple testwidget that reproduces the problem in a very simple way (thanks to Remi Rousselet for the simplification of the problem).

```dart
testWidgets('This test should pass but fails', (tester) async {
  final future = Future<void>.error(42);

  await tester.pumpWidget(FutureBuilder(
    future: future,
    builder: (_, snapshot) {
      return Container();
    },
  ));
});
```

**Expected result**

I expected the test to complete without error. Instead it fails with the following error :

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The number 42 was thrown running a test.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#2      main.<anonymous closure> (file:///C:/Projects/projet_65/mobile_app/test/ui/exception_test.dart:79:18)
#5      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTestBody (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:0:0)
#8      TestWidgetsFlutterBinding._runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:577:14)
#9      AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:993:24)
#15     AutomatedTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.runTest (package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart:990:15)
#16     testWidgets.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_test/src/widget_tester.dart:106:22)
#17     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:168:27)
#20     Declarer.test.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/declarer.dart:0:0)
#21     Invoker.waitForOutstandingCallbacks.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:250:15)
#27     Invoker._onRun.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:test_api/src/backend/invoker.dart:399:21)
(elided 17 frames from class _FakeAsync, package dart:async, and package dart:async-patch)

The test description was:
  This test should pass but fails
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried to `expect` the error like I would have done if it wasn't in a `Future` with:

```dart
expect(tester.takeException(), equals(42));
```

But that statement fails with the following error

```dart
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test (but after the test had completed):
  Expected: 42
  Actual: null
```

**edit:**

@shb answer is correct for the case exposed. Here's a slight modification that break it and gives back the initial error. This case is more susceptible to happen in real apps (and that's the case for me)

```dart
  testWidgets('This test should pass but fails', (tester) async {
      Future future;

      await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(
          home: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: const Text('GO'),
                onPressed: () { future = Future.error(42);},
              ),
              FutureBuilder(
                future: future,
                builder: (_, snapshot) {
                  return Container();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));

      await tester.tap(find.text('GO'));
  });
```

note: I have voluntarily ommitted the `tester.runAsync` proposed by @shb to match the initial question as it does not work in that particular case

Comment: (Never mind, disregard my earlier comments.)

Comment: @Muldec what happens if you wrap the `tester.tap` in `runAsync`?

Comment: @RémiRousselet same error plus a new one `The following assertion was thrown running a test (but after the test had completed): 'package:flutter_test/src/binding.dart': Failed assertion: line 1020 pos 12: '_currentFakeAsync !=null': is not true.` (meaning that two error are raised by the test)

Answer (score 15):

Wrap your code with  `await tester.runAsync(() async { .. }`

From the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/LiveTestWidgetsFlutterBinding/runAsync.html) `runAsync<T>`

> Runs a callback that performs real asynchronous work.
>
> This is intended for callers who need to call asynchronous methods
>   where the methods spawn isolates or OS threads and thus cannot be
>   executed synchronously by calling pump.

see below

```
testWidgets('This test should pass but fails', (tester) async {

    await tester.runAsync(() async {

      final future = Future<void>.error(42);

      await tester.pumpWidget(FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (_, snapshot) {
          return Container();
        },
      ));

    });

  });
```

[image: test passed]

**EDIT:**

(second issue OP raised)

in such cases use

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
   tester.tap(find.text('GO'));
});
```

Full snippet below

```
testWidgets('2nd try This test should pass but fails', (tester) async {

Future future;
await tester.runAsync(() async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('GO'),
            onPressed: () {
              future = Future.error(42);
            },
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: future,
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {tester.tap(find.text('GO'));});
});
});
```

[image: screenshot]

**Edit 2:**

It was later found that

`Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () { tester.tap(find.text('GO')); });`

is not being called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This solves the initial question asked. I edited the post to credit your answer and add a code where this solution does not work (the problem has been over simplified initially). What do you think of it ?

Comment: the test doesn't fail but the `Future` in the `Future.delayed` isn't called either. I've added a `print` statement to check if the code is run, but nothing is displayed on the console.

Comment: @Muldec yeah Looks so. I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: Have you tried awaiting the future? Also instead of `Future.delayed`, consider `Future.microtask`.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Future.microtask does execute but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 12):

Futures report errors to their listeners. If a `Future` doesn't have listeners it informs the `Zone` about the uncaught error ([src](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/6e77e52dbd433cf5e4f34b0d90190ff562c24e05/sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart#L551-L557)). This is where the testing framework gets the error from.

One way to overcome this error is to wait for listeners before erroring the `Future`.

```dart
  testWidgets('This passes', (tester) async {
    final Completer completer = Completer();
    await tester.pumpWidget(FutureBuilder(
      future: completer.future,
      builder: (_, snapshot) {
        return Container();
      },
    ));

    // has subscribers, doesn't inform Zone about uncought error
    completer.completeError(42);
    tester.pumpAndSettle();
  });
```

Comment: This is true if you have the control over the error. How about a code that throw an error depending of a specific case ? How would you handle it ? I updated my question with a slightly more complex code.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the problem is that you're not catching the error and that makes the app crash.

I've tried catching the error and the test passes:

here is the code:

```
testWidgets('This test should pass but fails', (tester) async {
    Future future;

    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
      home: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: const Text('GO'),
            onPressed: () {
              future = Future.error(42).catchError((error) {});
            },
          ),
          FutureBuilder(
            future: future,
            builder: (_, snapshot) {
              return Container();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));

    await tester.tap(find.text('GO'));
  });
```

Comment: Yes and no. When there is an error in the future builder, it takes the data as null. But the Future itself should use a catchError for that case.

Comment: @SergioBernal's point seems valid. the test passes for Future.value(42);

Comment: Problem is : the `catchError` on the `Future` handles the error and ruins the point of the `snapshot.hasError` in the `FutureBuilder.builder`. This will return false has the error has been handled. So testing (and using) the behavior of the `FutureBuilder` becomes unclear as to why the error message displayed to the user is done on `!snapshot.hasData` and not on `snapshot.hasError`.

Comment: @SergioBernal FutureBuilder already calls `catchError` on the `Future`. The issue is not that it's not caught, but caught asynchronously.

Comment: This code just suppresses the error which is not normally an acceptable solution.